# How to get values in mongdb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo, pymongo-3.x

This is my my data in Mongodb

```
{
    "d" :  {
        "results" :  [
            {
                "slack_id" :  "RAGHU@TN.COM",
                "connector_id" :  "GRECLNT900",
                "sys_role" :  "DEV",
                "user_id" :  "RAGHU"     
            },
            {
                "slack_id" :  "RAGHU@TN.COM",
                "connector_id" :  "GRECLNT900",
                "sys_role" :  "PRD",
                "user_id" :  "RAGHU",
               "question" : "What is your favorite color?",
               "Answer" : "Orange"      
            },         
         ]  
     }
}
```

If i am giving RAGHU@TN.COM. then i want display sys_role. Output like this`[DEV, PRD]`

I am trying this way

```
x = mydb.mycollection.distinct("sys-role")
```

But I get an empty array like `[ ]`

Comment: check `mydb.mycollection.distinct("d.results.sys-role")`

Comment: Still get empty array like [ ]

Comment: Ok. Thank you ,It's working

Answer (score 1):

You have to treat the cursor as a reference(personally I see it as a reference in C), and then de-reference it to see the result.(What is inside the address)
For the specific column, here is the result from command prompt:

```
my_cursor = mydb.mycollection.distinct("sys-role")
for x in my_cursor:
    print('{0}'.format(x['sys_role']))
```

Answer (score 0):

The distinct operator is not inter-operatable thus it's hard to filter by slack_id first. I would recommande using aggregation pipelines.
Here is an example.

```
[
  {
    '$match': {
      'slack_id': 'RAGHU@TN.COM'
    }
  }, {
    '$group': {
      '_id': 'slack_id', 
      'result': {
        '$addToSet': 'sys_role'
      }
    }
  }
]
```

With this pipeline, your `sys_role` set will be in the `.result` field.

Comment: I am getting Output like this : <pymongo.command_cursor.CommandCursor object at 0x000001CF14F0FE80>

Comment: Can you show me your code of how you call this aggregation?

Comment: v= mydb.mycol.aggregate([
  {
    '$match': {
      'slack_id': 'RAGHU@TN.COM'
    }
  }, {
    '$group': {
      '_id': 'slack_id',
      'result': {
        '$addToSet': 'sys_role'
      }
    }
  }
])

print(v)

Comment: `for data in v: print(data)`. please check the documentation of pymongo :). https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/command_cursor.html

Answer (score 0):

Using Mongo aggregation query you will get required result set. Try this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "d.results.slack_id": "RAGHU@TN.COM"
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$d.results.slack_id",
      sys_role: {
        $push: "$d.results.sys_role"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
db.getCollection("collection").aggregate(

    // Pipeline
    [
        // Stage 1
        {
            $project: {
                 results: {
                        $filter: {
                           input: "$d.results",
                           as: "item",
                           cond: { $eq: [ "$$item.slack_id", 'RAGHU@TN.COM' ] }
                        }
                     }
            }
        },

        // Stage 2
        {
            $unwind: {
                path : "$results",
                preserveNullAndEmptyArrays : false // optional
            }
        },

        // Stage 3
        {
            $group: {
            _id:'$results.slack_id',
            sys_roles:{$addToSet:'$results.sys_role'}
            }
        },

    ]



);
```